# Is there any hook or call back when a user is deleted from auth0 dashboard?

Tags: java, spring, webhooks, auth0

Is there any, way to create hook or call back that Auth0 will trigger once a user is deleted using the auth0 dashboard?

Thanks

Comment: Jai - having answered your question, please acknowledge by marking the answer as correct if it helped your understanding :)

Comment: Hi Jai, believe i have fully addressed your question. Be grateful if you would acknowledge my marking the answer correct. if anything unclear, pls leave a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a feature does not exist today (26/09/2017). However, you are free to write your own API for example, that will retrieve an API Management v2 token, use that to call Auth0 API and delete a user, then perform whatever (web) hook operation you had in mind. Make sense?

If you can explain further your scenario, and why you were asking for such a feature, may be able to offer an alternative that addresses your requirements.. Please leave me comments below if you like.

Ok, based on your last round of comments - please take a look at [Auth0 Custom DB Connection.](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db) This might be what you are looking for - note here, the specific questions you are asking would make more sense where you are NOT migrating your users over to Auth0 if you wish to use the Dashboard for delete operations. For an Auth0 custom db connection, where you are not migrating users, then you can write a Delete script that would be triggered from dashboard.

[image]

Comment: I want to maintain my database to replicate the Auth0 users. when the changes happens in Auth0 users, i need to update my data base as well. how can i will achieve?

Comment: In that situation, the approach I recommend in answer would work. Initiate the auth0 deletion from a trusted server you control, and then as part of a composite service, do likewise to your own DB. If you don't have a server of your own, one option is to consider using an Auth0 webtask (https://webtask.io/) - effectively a serverless approach.

Comment: The question over which to delete first (auth0 record or your own record) is a judgement call. You don't have 2 phase commit (easy rollback) - for instance if your business logic dictates it makes sense to remove the record from your DB first, then do it in that order. When dealing with large enterprises using SAP systems etc, the preference here is usually to delete from SAP before removal of the Auth0 user profile and credentials info.

Comment: When i the auth0 record delete directly in dashboard, i have to update my database as well. how can i will achieve?

Comment: Don't use the dashboard for delete operations. Instead use your own API. Let me ask you a question - are you wishing to migrate your credentials into Auth0 - or are you happy to keep that in your own DB?  If the latter, then you could take a look at Auth0 Custom DB. Will update my answer above.

Comment: I have to do the hook when the when user deleted from my dashboard. That's business. still am looking the solution

Comment: In that case, as I have already stated in answer above, it depends whether you want to store Credentials in Auth0 or not. If you do store in Auth0, then today you would have to orchestrate to delete from two data stores separately - or use a custom DB connection and then the Dashboard delete would remove the Auth0 user profile and the record in your DB.  We do have web hooks on Management API endpoints on our roadmap for a future release.

Comment: We don't have delete hook option in Auth0, so that we have to do a cron only!! My understanding was right?